# Qt remote database with MySql?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt

What is the best way to add remote MySql database connectivity.

I have attempted using the QODBC driver with no luck, I believe another issue may be that this is a shared server but believe I have the right [settings according to my host](https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/6).

Here is my current attempt:

```
bool CardSQL::connectSQL(void){
     db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC"); 
     db.setHostName("173.254.28.127");// Tried www.themindspot.com & ip with http:// and https:// 
     db.setPort(3306);
     db.setDatabaseName("dbName");
     db.setUserName("dbUser");
     db.setPassword("dbPass");
     bool ok = db.open();
     return ok;
}
```

I check 'ok' in a if statement and it keeps coming back failed.

Comment: Dumb question but...are you sure the remote database is running on a publicly exported IP address and port? Also, if its MySql, wouldn't you want `QMYSQL` ?

Comment: According to the link above it is and I added my ip to the remote access list.  I didn't have the QMYSQL driver and was trying to avoid the process of building one and it seems people are able to use this in its place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your MySQL server on your justhost.com shared host is not running on a public network interface, and is only accessible via localhost (meaning you have to be running your apps locally on the server to connect). If there is an option to do it, its probably not currently doing it.

Some cpanel configurations have a "Remote Database Access Hosts" option which lets you specify specific external domains that are allowed to connect to your MySQL database.

Also, for mysql you would probably be using the `QMYSQL` database driver.

Comment: I added my ip to the remote access list.  It looks like I am going to need and build a QMYSQL driver.  My head hurts...  Thank you, and keep everyone updated on what happens when I get it done.